# Filter only on ng-show and after certain characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a text input for adding comments. A user can type an @ symbol in the input to bring up a list of users. They can then choose a user to add them to the comment. I need to be able to filter the usernames based on the text that is typed after the @ symbol. So "@s" would filter all usernames and or first name/last names with an "s". Is there a way to only run a filter when the user list is shown, and only filter based on the input that is typed after the @ symbol? Here is what I currently have:

HTML/SLIM:

```
/ USER LIST
.user-list.list-group [ng-show="usersShow"]
  a.user.list-group-item [ng-class="{active:$first}" ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="addUserToComment(user.username)"]
    strong
      | {{user.username}}
    | {{' : ' + (user | fullName)}}

/ COMMENT FORM
= form_for Comment.new, html: {action: nil, name: 'newCommentForm', 'ng-submit' => 'createComment($event, comment)'} do |f|

   = f.text_field :text, required: true, class: 'form-control comment-text', placeholder: 'Add comment...',
  'ng-model' => 'comment.text', 'ng-change' => 'showUserList(comment.text)', 'ng-trim' => 'false'
    span.input-group-btn
      button.btn.btn-primary type="submit" ng-disabled='newCommentForm.$invalid' Add Comment
```

JS:

```
$scope.showUserList = function(comment) {
  var USERNAME_PATTERN = /(?:^|\s)@\S*$/;
  $scope.usersShow = USERNAME_PATTERN.test(comment);
};
```

Comment: You could add a filter to the "user in users" ng-repeat, and have the filter function get the value of the text input to use to filter the list.

Comment: @aet Thank you. I tried something similar to that. My problem is that I only want the filter to run when the list is shown, and on the characters after the @ symbol, every time an @ is typed.

Comment: Any way you could put this in a plunkr or jsfiddle? Your ng-show should control the list visibility. ng-repeat will keep the list filtered. Might have to put a capture group in your regex to get the text after the @.

Comment: @aet Thanks again for your help. I will try to put this in a fiddle. I have the user list show and hide working based on what is typed into the comment field. It's just the filter part. I am working on something like you suggested. I'm watching the field and trying to pull the text after the @ symbol. Then hopefully I can use that for the filter.